# Node.js on Amazon EC2 faster development, have to kill PID everytime i change something

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

i am developing on a amazon EC2 server, running node.js with express.

I run the server by doing a `sudo node server.js` and its fune, i can see the requests coming in etc. But when i change something and reupload, a send a `ctrl+Z` a SIGTERM.

This gives me back the session, but it does not completly shut down the server, when i try to run it again by doing `sudo node server.js` it tells me the port is in use, so i have to do a

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Get process id and

```
kill -9 PRCOCESS_ID
```

This gets quite annoying in the long run when developing. Any faster way?

Comment: ctrl-C is a SIGINT, not SIGTERM, if that matters for your code.

Comment: Sorry, i meant Ctrl-Z

Comment: Ctrl-Z is not SIGTERM.  What you are doing is *suspending* the process, so it's still there.  Use ctrl-C, or `kill` it.

Comment: yea the real answer here is use ctrl + c.   nodemon is a bandaid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `nodemon`: it will automatically restart the server after changes.  https://github.com/remy/nodemon

I picked up on that from this [Medium post](https://medium.com/tech-talk/e7c0b0e5ce3c), it has some other good Node tips in it.